# Web Page dashboard to see general health checks (IIS)

Tags: .net, iis, health-check

I have a bunch of APIs, web services, databases, file shares, and I'd like to have the ability to see in one place their health status, but I'd like to avoid writing custom code.

The idea would be to configure on a settings file or something the URLs, connection strings and then on a dashboard see the workloads and its status (healthy or "dirty").

Is there anything out of the box that I can use or customize, that can be hosted on IIS and/or apply customization with .Net or .Net Core?

Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few dashboard frameworks you can use, but I doubt any of them is written in .NET. More can be found from a search engine like,  https://www.metricfire.com/blog/top-8-open-source-dashboards/

Comment: I found such an official Microsoft article：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/monitor-app-health